# Pandas/Python - Group data by same period in time

Tags: python, pandas

I have some financial data and want to get only the last transaction from a specific period of time (hours, days, months...).

Example:

```
>>df
      time  price_BRL     qt              time_dt
1312001297      23.49   1.00  2011-07-30 04:48:17
1312049148      23.40   1.00  2011-07-30 18:05:48
1312121523      23.49   2.00  2011-07-31 14:12:03
1312121523      23.50   6.50  2011-07-31 14:12:03
1312177622      23.40   2.00  2011-08-01 05:47:02
1312206416      23.25   1.00  2011-08-01 13:46:56
1312637929      18.95   1.50  2011-08-06 13:38:49
1312637929      18.95   4.00  2011-08-06 13:38:49
1312817114       0.80   0.01  2011-08-08 15:25:14
1312818289       0.10   0.01  2011-08-08 15:44:49
1312819795       6.00   0.09  2011-08-08 16:09:55
1312847064      16.00   0.86  2011-08-08 23:44:24
1312849282      16.00   6.14  2011-08-09 00:21:22
1312898146      19.90   1.00  2011-08-09 13:55:46
1312915666       6.00   0.01  2011-08-09 18:47:46
1312934897      19.90   1.00  2011-08-10 00:08:17
>>filter_by_last_day(df)
      time  price_BRL     qt              time_dt
1312049148      23.40   1.00  2011-07-30 18:05:48
1312121523      23.50   6.50  2011-07-31 14:12:03
1312206416      23.25   1.00  2011-08-01 13:46:56
1312637929      18.95   4.00  2011-08-06 13:38:49
1312847064      16.00   0.86  2011-08-08 23:44:24
1312915666       6.00   0.01  2011-08-09 18:47:46
1312934897      19.90   1.00  2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

I was thinking in using `groupby()` and get the `mean()` for that day (this solution is also possible for my problem, but not exactly) but don't know how to select the day like `df.groupby('time.day').last()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and aggregate by [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
#if necessery convert to datetime
df.time_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.time_dt)

df = df.groupby(df.time_dt.dt.date).last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         time  price_BRL    qt             time_dt
0  1312049148      23.40  1.00 2011-07-30 18:05:48
1  1312121523      23.50  6.50 2011-07-31 14:12:03
2  1312206416      23.25  1.00 2011-08-01 13:46:56
3  1312637929      18.95  4.00 2011-08-06 13:38:49
4  1312847064      16.00  0.86 2011-08-08 23:44:24
5  1312915666       6.00  0.01 2011-08-09 18:47:46
6  1312934897      19.90  1.00 2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

Thank you [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654286/pandas-python-group-data-by-same-period-in-time/41654485?noredirect=1#comment70508018_41654485) for another solution - add parameter `as_index=False` for return `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby(df.time_dt.dt.date, as_index=False).last()
print (df)
         time  price_BRL    qt             time_dt
0  1312049148      23.40  1.00 2011-07-30 18:05:48
1  1312121523      23.50  6.50 2011-07-31 14:12:03
2  1312206416      23.25  1.00 2011-08-01 13:46:56
3  1312637929      18.95  4.00 2011-08-06 13:38:49
4  1312847064      16.00  0.86 2011-08-08 23:44:24
5  1312915666       6.00  0.01 2011-08-09 18:47:46
6  1312934897      19.90  1.00 2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

Solution with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), but is necessery remove `NaN` rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.resample('d', on='time_dt').last().dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
#cast column time to int
df.time = df.time.astype(int)
print (df)
         time  price_BRL    qt             time_dt
0  1312049148      23.40  1.00 2011-07-30 18:05:48
1  1312121523      23.50  6.50 2011-07-31 14:12:03
2  1312206416      23.25  1.00 2011-08-01 13:46:56
3  1312637929      18.95  4.00 2011-08-06 13:38:49
4  1312847064      16.00  0.86 2011-08-08 23:44:24
5  1312915666       6.00  0.01 2011-08-09 18:47:46
6  1312934897      19.90  1.00 2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

### ---

You can also use [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.time_dt.dt.month).last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         time  price_BRL   qt             time_dt
0  1312121523       23.5  6.5 2011-07-31 14:12:03
1  1312934897       19.9  1.0 2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

With `hours` it is a bit complicated, if need `groupby` by `date` and `hours` together, solution is replace `minutes` and `seconds` to `0` by `astype`:

```
hours = df.time_dt.values.astype('<M8[h]')
print (hours)
['2011-07-30T04' '2011-07-30T18' '2011-07-31T14' '2011-07-31T14'
 '2011-08-01T05' '2011-08-01T13' '2011-08-06T13' '2011-08-06T13'
 '2011-08-08T15' '2011-08-08T15' '2011-08-08T16' '2011-08-08T23'
 '2011-08-09T00' '2011-08-09T13' '2011-08-09T18' '2011-08-10T00']

df = df.groupby(hours).last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
          time  price_BRL    qt             time_dt
0   1312001297      23.49  1.00 2011-07-30 04:48:17
1   1312049148      23.40  1.00 2011-07-30 18:05:48
2   1312121523      23.50  6.50 2011-07-31 14:12:03
3   1312177622      23.40  2.00 2011-08-01 05:47:02
4   1312206416      23.25  1.00 2011-08-01 13:46:56
5   1312637929      18.95  4.00 2011-08-06 13:38:49
6   1312818289       0.10  0.01 2011-08-08 15:44:49
7   1312819795       6.00  0.09 2011-08-08 16:09:55
8   1312847064      16.00  0.86 2011-08-08 23:44:24
9   1312849282      16.00  6.14 2011-08-09 00:21:22
10  1312898146      19.90  1.00 2011-08-09 13:55:46
11  1312915666       6.00  0.01 2011-08-09 18:47:46
12  1312934897      19.90  1.00 2011-08-10 00:08:17
```

Comment: why not just `df.groupby(df.time_dt.dt.date, as_index=False).last()`?